# Display random image with visual basic

Tags: image, random

In Visual Studio 2010 (using vb) I'm trying to find a way to display a random image in the picture box of my form for each time the code enters the loop below. I would like to add 30 or so images to the project with names, e.g. image_1 ... image_30. Each time the code enters the loop, I'd like the picture box to display one of the 30 images at random. Does anyone know if a random number can be placed in the name of the photo, e.g. image_randnum.jpg?

```
If CheckTheAnswer() Then
        randnum = randomizer.Next(30)
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.photo_randnum.jpg
Endif
```

Thanks and sorry if this is a remedial question...

Paul Safier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just name your images Image_0, Image_1, Image_2 ... etc. And then you can call them like this:

```
If CheckTheAnswer() Then
    randnum = Random.Next(30)
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image_" & randnum.ToString())
End If
```